# Algolia with Cloud Firestore using Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I know that Algolia can work perfectly fine with Firebase Realtime database but is there any way in which we can implement Algolia with Cloud Firestore using Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Syncing

Syncing and indexing of data in Algolia are usually done in the backend (with Node.js for example). In the case of syncing Cloud Firestore and Algolia, you will need to use [Firestore events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) in order to listen to new changes in Firestore and make the proper changes in Algolia (as described in their [full-text search docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/search), which is in Node.js).

### Search

In order to search your data from Algolia in your Android app, you will need to use the Algolia mobile SDK that is written in Android (see [Getting started for Android](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/android/getting-started/)). If you want to query your Cloud Firestore, then you can separately use the Firebase SDK to achieve that.

Comment: @IoanaP. You can take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O6x-ZJp-10)** where I have explained step by step, how you can achieve this.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks! I'll take a look.

Comment: That's awesome @AlexMamo thanks for producing this content! FYI just a typo on the title: `Algolia` not `Alogolia`

Comment: @GuyDaher Thank you for your comment and for the typo. Just edited my description and hope that other developers will also find this video useful. Thanks for helping develop a great service. Cheers!

Comment: Do you actually need Algolia? Couldn't I simply have a textlistener on an EditText, and pass that text into the query, to populate a RecyclerView?